# SourceFire/Snort/FirePower Custom Regex Rule Error

Tags: ids, snort

I am getting an `unknown/extra pcre option encountered`error when trying to save my custom rule.

```
^([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$
```

The rule is to match UK Vehicle Registrations.
[image]

Does anyone know why this rule is not saving correctly?
I have tried to add this rule as a "Sensitive Data Detection" rule, but it does not trigger (assuming due to the error below!).

Comment: Could it be that snort needs the `/` delimiters around the regex?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have accepted it now! However, it is still not triggering on test data for some reason....

Comment: Is the `^`...`$` intentional? Do you want to match if the packet *only* contains the vehicle number?